# How to pass in the path to a creds.py as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file where I have a script. To run this particular script, I do need some credentials like access token and stuff residing in `Creds.py`.

The `Script.py` looks like this

```
from Creds import *
# more code
```

`Creds.py` looks like this

```
base_path = ""
url_access_token = "https://login.officialsite.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
object_id = "e59d755d-46dfgd9a-4c3c-aae2-aabae3345a1b831"
url_messages = "https://officialsite.officialsite.com/v1.0/users/{0}/messages?$filter=isRead ne true&$count=true"
```

Now I need to pass in the path where `Creds.py` resides so that we can take that arg and then import the credentials as a module.
Any idea how to do that?

Edit:
I want to pass in the path for the file - Creds.py using command liine interface while running the script using python Script.py

Comment: Please clarify in code what you mean.   With what you have in ```Script.py```, you could simply use ```url_access_token``` (or whatever)..  or did I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Puneeth What you mrean by `pass in the path`? Does it mean you want your base_path variable to be passed an argument, or do you mean to pass the correct path of `creds.py` in your `from Creds import * ` line? Please rephrase your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I want to pass in the path for the file - Creds.py using command liine interface while running the script using python Script.py <path here>

Comment: You can use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) or [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to get command line arguments.